# code generating seg fault when migrating from gcc 4.2 to 4.8

Tags: c, gcc

I have some c code that is crashing after I migrated the system from one server to another.  It worked when compiled under gcc 4.2.1 but under 4.8 it crashes... here is the code:

```
void initcap(char *inbuf) {
/* freshen case in string, capitalize first letters */

  char *ptr;

  *ptr=toupper(*inbuf); /* first letter must be cap causing SEG fault */
  for (ptr=inbuf+1; *ptr; ptr++) {
    if ( (isspace(*(ptr-1))) || (ispunct(*(ptr-1))) || (isdigit(*(ptr-1))) )
      *ptr=toupper(*ptr);
    else
      *ptr=tolower(*ptr);
  }
}
```

the line that's causing the seg fault is: *ptr=toupper(*inbuf);

Can someone explain what has changed in my environment that might make it work ok on one system and not on a more modern server?  And what is the work-around?  Should I search other areas of my code for similar problems?

Comment: `char *ptr;` is uninitialised so this is to do with the code not the compiler. Please enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Please compile your example with `-Wall` before posting it here.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *ptr;

*ptr=toupper(*inbuf); /* first letter must be cap causing SEG fault */
```

Pop quiz time: what is `ptr` pointing to here?

If you've answered "nuthin", you won! It's not initialized, so it's initial contents are random garbage. Congratulations on scrambling a randomly-pointed to byte in your process address space. You've won a completely random segfault and a crash.

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect:

```
*ptr=toupper(*inbuf);
```

Change it to:

```
*inbuf=toupper(*inbuf)
```

I think this code never worked correctly in the first place. The first character was never converted to upper case correctly.

What actually happened was that you wrote to a semi-random memory address in that line, corrupting memory somewhere, because `ptr` wasn't initialized at that point. In the old compiler version, it happened to have a value pointing to an existing (but still probably unwanted) memory location, so it didn't crash. This appears to have changed now, that's why you see it now crashing.

By the way, you might also want to add `if(!*inbuf) return;` above it, otherwise the function will misbehave when an empty string is given.

Comment: Thank you so much for actually being useful instead of snarky and mean. It's much appreciated

I'm wondering if, since this is in a virtualized environment, there's much more strict memory management and that is what is causing it to generate an error?   In previous versions of gcc under FreeBSD there was no warning generated.

Comment: As I said, it never worked. Your program went ahead and, like, wrote the first character of its text not into the book it was supposed to, but to a random location. Previously, it happened to be a wall so nothing happened other than that the letter wasn't written correctly. Now, it happens to be a cow, which is now kicking you when you try to write something onto it. See what I mean? And what exactly caused the random location to land on a cow this time is hard to say and actually the wrong question because you should just close your eyes and write a letter somewhere random anyway.

Comment: should => shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

You have *undefined behaviour* with this:

```
char *ptr;
*ptr=toupper(*inbuf);
```

because `ptr` is uninitialised. The intention was to uppercase the first character, so it should be:

```
*inbuf = toupper(*inbuf);
```

Please enable all compiler warnings to catch this sort of mistake.

Comment: What is the option to enable the warning that would have caught this?